# Using Async Parallel for multiple MongoDB aggregate functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, async.js

Hello I need to do multiple aggregate queries, and render the results to a view. My problem right now is figuring out how to make sure all the queries finish before rendering them and I have come upon async.parallel. I have been trying to mess with it but it is not working. For example, this is what I have right now.

```
    var async = require('async');
    async.parallel({
    one: function(){
        Country.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                name: { $in: ["USA", "China", "India", "France", "Japan"]},
                }
            },
            {
                $sort: {
                    year: 1
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: '$name',
                    nominalGDP: {$push: "$nominalGDP"}
                }
            }, 
            {
                $project: {
                _id: 0,
                name: "$_id",
                nominalGDP: 1
                }
            }
            ], function(err, recs){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(recs);
            }
        });
    },

    two: function(){
        Country.aggregate([
            {           
                $match: {
                    $and: [
                        {name: { $in: ["USA", "China", "India", "France", "Japan"]}},
                        {year: 2017}
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                $sort: {
                    "nominalGDP": -1
                }
            },
            {
                $project: {
                _id: 0,
                name: 1,
                'y' : '$nominalGDP'
                }
            }       
            ], function(err, recs){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(recs);
            }
        });
    }
}, function(err, results){
    res.render('random', { title: 'Test', data: results.one, pie: results.two });
});
```

So I have two aggregate functions that each produce their results. The two functions are printing their results properly, but no data is being rendered to my view (random).

Comment: what do you expect `results.one` and `results.two` will be? Neither of the functions returns anything either, so, how do you expect the results to be available in `function(err, results)` ?

Comment: change `one: function(){` to `one: function(callback){` ... and instead of `function(err, recs){ .... }` replace that with `callback` ... repeat for `two`

Comment: ohhh i see. well just adding 'callback' like how h1b9b and Jaromanda X said did the trick, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tasks have the `callback` function as argument
So the return data from a task, it should look like

```
task: function(callback) {
   ...
   callback(null, result);
}
```

In this case, you can use the `callback` as the second argument to `Country.aggregate`

Comment: or, in the case of the code in the question, instead of using `function(err, recs) { .... }` just use `callback`

Answer (score 0):

Parllel require a callback function which make sure that function is fully executed and now its time to return.

Even callback take 2 parameters , 
1. Err (which will null if success)
2. Data(which need to send in success)

```
var async = require('async');
    async.parallel({
    one: function(cb){
        Country.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                name: { $in: ["USA", "China", "India", "France", "Japan"]},
                }
            },
            {
                $sort: {
                    year: 1
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: '$name',
                    nominalGDP: {$push: "$nominalGDP"}
                }
            }, 
            {
                $project: {
                _id: 0,
                name: "$_id",
                nominalGDP: 1
                }
            }
            ], function(err, recs){
            if(err){
               cb(err);
            } else {
               cb (null , recs);
            }
        });
    },

    two: function(cb){
        Country.aggregate([
            {           
                $match: {
                    $and: [
                        {name: { $in: ["USA", "China", "India", "France", "Japan"]}},
                        {year: 2017}
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                $sort: {
                    "nominalGDP": -1
                }
            },
            {
                $project: {
                _id: 0,
                name: 1,
                'y' : '$nominalGDP'
                }
            }       
            ], function(err, recs){
            if(err){

                cb(err);
            } else {
               cb(null, recs);
            }
        });
    }
}, function(err, results){
    res.render('random', { title: 'Test', data: results.one, pie: results.two });
});
```

You can read further details on 
https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md#parallel